# Where is the LinkedIn Profile Views chart in the new web app interface?

Tags: linkedin

LinkedIn has recently updated the web app's interface.

I  am using a Premium account and used to be able to see a chart with the weekly **Profile Views** count (see example from the web attached).

Now with the new interface, LinkedIn displays a list of people who have seen my profile (Who Your Viewers Are) but I can't find the weekly or monthly profile count that used to be displayed in a chart.

Where can I find that feature?

[image]

Comment: I think this features has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Option to see LinkedIn profile views also exists in free version. 
You can find the trend chart at https://www.linkedin.com/me/profile-views/
Make sure you are logged in first.

Comment: Not anymore I think..

Comment: Was anybody able to find the graph in the latest version?